# Qt Jambi and designer: resources

Tags: qt, qt-jambi

I am struggling figuring out how to add resources/icons properly to the Qt Designer with Jambi.

When I simply add an icon and go for "Choose file", my .jui looks like

`<normaloff>../../../../images/fatcow/32x32/add.png</normaloff>../../../../images/fatcow/32x32/add.png</iconset>`

As opposed to desired `classpath:*#`.

Of course I can just run sed to substitute on all jui files, but is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: What are full paths of jui and png files?

Comment: ~/Ebay/Flogger/images/fatcow/32x32/*.png
~/Ebay/Flogger/src/com/flogger/gui/*.jui

I tried moving them around, but haven't achieved much.

Comment: Right, "solved" the following way: moved images folder to the same folder as *.jui and then created a link to images at the root of the project. I see it more of a hack, since the jui is still missing "classpath:*#".

Answer (score 0):

Add them from Java, not Qt Designer.

I wanted to do something like this, and ended up instead using the following code, which allows me to use the desktop's native icons:

```
ui.actionNew.setIcon( QIcon.fromTheme( "document-new" ) );
ui.actionOpen.setIcon( QIcon.fromTheme( "document-open" ) );
```

Sorry for an answer-in-the-negative, but doing this seemed more time efficient to me than trying to do so in the designer.